# SwiftData sort or filter enum property

Tags: swift, swift-data, ios17

Now that SwiftData can correctly store enums in our models, I am now having difficulties trying to filter or sort on that property.
For example
status is an enum

```
enum Status: String, Codable, CaseIterable, Identifiable, Comparable {
   static func < (lhs: Status, rhs: Status) -> Bool {
     lhs.rawValue < rhs.rawValue
   }
   case toRead = "On Shelf"
   case inProgress = "Currently Reading"
   case completed = "Completed"
   var id: Self {
      return self
   }
}
```

My model is something like this

```
class Book: Hashable {
   var title: String
   var author: String
   var status: Status

   init(
     title: String,
     author: String,
     status: Status = .toRead
   ) {
     self.title = title
     self.author = author
     self.status = status
   }
}
```

The data gets stored in the db as a String

When I try to do this.

```
@Query(sort: \Book.status) private var books: [Book]
```

The app crashes with the error

> keypath status not found in entity Book

I have tried using a computed Int property but I cannot seem to use a keyPath to a computed property either.
Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug/limitation of SwiftData?

Comment: This is not supported (yet?). You have to store the `rawValue` of the `status` property instead. Thus you can sort your books with `\Book.statusRawValue`. To access any book's status you will need a new `status` computed property `var status: Status { .init(rawValue: statusRawValue)! }`.

Comment: You don’t have to store the raw value.  Swift Data does that for you now. That was fixed in beta 7.  Your models can have enum properties that conform to codable.  However, you cannot sort on them even if you make them conform to Comparable.  The workaround is what I have been doing, but what is the point of being able to have enum as properties if you can’t sort or filter by them?